# How can I use same prop in multiple functional components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

This is my `App.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import SoltM from './slot';
const App = ()=>{
  return(
    <>
    <div>
    <SlotM x="emoji1" y="emoji1" z="emoji1" />
    <hr />
    <SlotM x="emoji2" y="emoji3" z="emoji3" />
    <hr />
    <SlotM x="emoji3" y="emoji3" z="emoji3" />
    <hr />
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is my `SlotM.jsx` component, in this, props are not displayed in True or False component.

```js
import React from 'react';
const SlotM = (props) => {
  return ( (props.x === props.y && props.y === props.z) )}
const True = (props) => {
  let { x, y, z } = props
  return (
    <>
      <div className="slot_inner">
        <h1> {x} {y} {z} </h1>
        <h1> This is Matching </h1>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
const False = (props) => {
  let { x, y, z } = props
  return (
    <>
      <div className="slot_inner">
        <h1> {x} {y} {z} </h1>
        <h1> This is not Matching. emoji1 </h1>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
export default SlotM;
```

[This is my app.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nNsm.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlDrE.png):[This is SlotM.jsx component in this props are not being displayed in True and False component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlDrE.png)

Comment: Where are you rendering your True or False components

Comment: Yup i checked it and resolved it Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread operator like this:
<True {...props} /> <False {...props} />

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood sth. `props.x === props.y && props.y === props.z) )` returns boolean value, not Function. How about this?

```
const SlotM = (props) => {
    return (props.x === props.y && props.y === props.z) ? <TrueC {...props}/>: <FalseC {...props}/>
} 

const TrueC = (props) => {
    ...

const FalseC = (props) => {
    ...
```